# Django - Testing with parts of original database

Tags: django, django-testing

My database has two types of entries: The very dynamic (users, comments, etc) and the more static (email templates, flat-pages).

During testing I want a clean DB but with the real 'semi-static' data.

Is there a way to make Django's testing system to load parts of the original DB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fixtures. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/initial-data/)
or the (wiki page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures)

Put data you need into fixtures and they will be loaded every time test database is built.

Comment: Not sure I understand how I dynamically get that data from the real db. Do I need to manually create them every time ? Or is there a way to make the tests auto-extract them ?

Comment: No, create a simple python script, that will select required data from the database and then build fixtures. Those fixtures will be inserted into the test database every time it is created.